# Paginating UIScrollView with infinite loop of three views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, pagination

I want to create a `UIScrollView` with three constant views. The middle view should always be displayed initially. When the user scrolls to the right, then View 1 will be the active view and the other two views will move as if there was a loop: View 3 will now be to the left, and View 2 on the right. The attached figure explains what I want: [image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 3 Pages Only
>
> There may be times when you want an infinite page loop, but don’t want
>   to load in a lot of content. For example, You may have a lot of
>   content to display inside the UIScrollView. Loading large amounts of
>   data there would not be the ideal approach to the situation.
>
> The logic
>   that we can use there is to keep the UIScrollView at just three pages.
>   Data would load on each page and the user would always be looking at
>   the data in the middle page. When the user scrolled to a new page, the
>   content for each page would be reset and the offset would go back the
>   user is back to viewing the middle page. That way even though you may
>   have a large amount of data to scroll through, it’s not all loaded at
>   once. Only three pages are ever loaded at one time.

... taken from http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Answer (score 0):

Make your scroll view 5 views in a row. make the first view view 3 the next 1, 2, 3, 1. Start the Scrollview where you want.

Answer (score -1):

Very possible.  You might subclass `UIScrollView` and drop something like this in its `- (id)init` method.

```
int numberOfPages = 3;

// For ease in referencing sizes
CGFloat portalHeight = self.frame.size.height;
CGFloat portalWidth = self.frame.size.width;

self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * numberOf Pages, self.frame.size.height);

self.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

// Needed to lock scrolling to pages
self.pagingEnabled = YES;

// Setup pages
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
    // Add subviews here
}
```

**EDIT:** I may not be completely understanding your question.  Should these be a 'carousel' of views that can loop around continuously?

Answer (score -1):

scroll3.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scroll3.frame.size.width*2, 0);